# Getting gulp and es6 set up to reload on saves

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browser-sync

I have been playing with gulp and babel for the past few days. I am getting a solid grasp of setting up babel with gulp through tutorials.  I've noticed that the newer the tutorial the more changes that develop.

Here is one way I was able to set up es6 to es5 with a transpiler.

```
var gulp  = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('es6to5', function () {
return gulp.src('js/src/app.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

However, I do not want to rerun gulp each time, and I want the dist/ folder to update on each save.

I added browser-sync and delete.

```
var gulp  = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var del = require('del');



gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
    return del([
            'dist/app.js'
        ]);
});

gulp.task('es6to5', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/src/app.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task("browserSync", function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dist'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task("copyIndex", ['clean:dist'], function() {
    gulp.src("src/index.html")
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('watchFiles', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/index.html', ['copyIndex']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['babelIt']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['clean:dist', 'es6to5','browserSync','watchFiles']);
```

I set up a default that will clean out the dist folder then run es6to5. Afterwards I want it to sync and update.  I called watchFiles last.

However, I am no longer getting updated js files.  The files in the  **dist folder**  Are not compiling to es5 and everything is going to a 404.

The task

```
copyIndex seems to be the problem but I am not sure how to fix it or if it is the only problem.  Any direction helps.
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve on change rebuild of `dist` for development purposes, serving your development build from that `dist` directory?

Comment: That is the what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo.

It should be `gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['es6to5']);`, not `gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['babelIt']);`

Anyway i suggest to use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) instead of the built-in `watch` function. It has several advantages, mainly it recompile on new file creation.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I removed the babel it task and did not catch the change.